# C++(GCC). Library curl. Statically linked

Tags: dll, gcc, curl, mingw

What options set, to statically linked the library curl ?

Library **should be integrated to executable file**.

*tried different: added options g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl ... added #define CURL_STATICLIB to the code ..., in the IDE NetBeans added libcurl.a, libcurldll.a ... etc.,*

Compile **is successful** and all works great. **But** still require **external libcurl.dll**! (Size of executable file also increases!)

What's wrong ? *might have something add to the IDE (also used NetBeans, Eclipse)*

Please show a correct example as you would make

Executable file should be **without** calling an external **dll** library

*it my first question* :)

---

Fix.

Example compile for library curl with OpenSSL + zlib + libidn + libssh2 + librtmp:

> g++ -static main.cpp -lcurl -lidn -lwldap32 -lssh2 -lz -lrtmp -lssl -lssl32 -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lws2_32 -lwinmm -o test.exe

note: here shouldn't be specified -lcurldll. This will lead to that: compile is successful, but still require external libcurl.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify `-static` in the linker options

Comment: thanks.,
I also made a mistake in the argument (used -lcurldll). if it is removed, will be a working programm without external lib.